# Imacros for FireFox - Loop Inside EVAL

Tags: javascript, firefox, loops, eval, imacros

I need to reload `URL` (in this case to refresh same page) until I don't have word beginning with capitalized A, B or C.

How can I loop inside `EVAL`? Can somebody please provide me with some code example?

```
VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomWord/RandomWord.aspx
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:tmpl_main_lblWord EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var re = /^[A || B || C]/gi; var str = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; while(str.search(re) == -1) {URL GOTO=http://watchout4snakes.com/CreativityTools/RandomWord/RandomWord.aspx}")
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

I already asked on iMacros forum, but I don't have answer until now.

With this part of code I need help, where `{{!EXTRACT}}` is extracted word (variable) from page. So, while `{{!EXTRACT}}` is not word that starts with uppercase letter A, B or C, I need to go again and again on the same `URL` (in this case to refresh same page):

```
var re = /^[A || B || C]/gi; 
var str = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; 
while(str.search(re) == -1) 
{
***go to this URL***
}
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is better you invert the situation here. Instead of writing a macro using EVAL with a loop inside, write a short javascript with a loop which calls a short macro.

You can run a javascript directly in iMacros for Firefox, just as you run a macro.

Have a look at http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface for more information on how to call iMacros commands from such a javascript.